# Designing a private message system for sending messages between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a messaging system in rails which will enable a user to send messages to a listing. Once they click on send message a new conversation is created between the user and and the listing. So a conversation is always between only 2 users.

here is basic setup

`User` has_many `Listings`

`Listing` belongs_to `User`

For adding private messaging system as described above I am planning like below

`Conversation` has_many `Messages`

`Message` belongs_to `Conversation`

`listing` has_many `conversation`

`user` has_many `conversation`

`conversation` belongs_to `listing`

`conversation` belongs_to `user`

I have never done something this crazy. I have a feeling that there is another better way to do this or am overkilling it. I know I easily create messaging if its between 2 users, but as a user can have many listings and I want a different conversation for each listing(so basically conversation is between a user and a listing) even its from the same owner. Could someone shed some light into which approach to go on schema design in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using has_many through for conversations:

---

User has_many Listings

Listing belongs_to User

Conversation belongs_to Listing

Conversation has_many Messages

Message belongs_to Conversation

Listing has_many Conversations

UserA has_many conversations, through: listing, class: User

UserB has_many conversations, through: listing, class: User

---

It would be nice to think of better names of UserA and UserB of course, but sender/recipient doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, does it work?

One question: are conversations ever going to exist between users? If so you may want to do some predictive naming of your objects, e.g. `ListingUserConversation`.